# segmentation fault in overloading operator =

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, overloading

I just got a seg fault in overloading the assignment operator for a class FeatureRandomCounts, which has _rects as its pointer member pointing to an array of FeatureCount and size rhs._dim, and whose other date members are non-pointers:

```
FeatureRandomCounts &  FeatureRandomCounts::operator=(const FeatureRandomCounts &rhs)  
{  
  if (_rects) delete [] _rects;  

  *this = rhs;  // segment fault

  _rects = new FeatureCount [rhs._dim];  
  for (int i = 0; i < rhs._dim; i++)  
  {  
    _rects[i]=rhs._rects[i];  
  }  

  return *this;    
}
```

Does someone have some clue? Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned, you have infinite recursion; however, to add to that, here's a foolproof way to implement op=:

```
struct T {
  T(T const& other);
  T& operator=(T copy) {
    swap(*this, copy);
    return *this;
  }
  friend void swap(T& a, T& b);
};
```

Write a correct copy ctor and swap, and exception safety and all edge cases are handled for you!

The *copy* parameter is *passed by value* and then changed.  Any resources which the current instance must destroy are handled when *copy* is destroyed.  This follows [current recommendations](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) and handles [self-assignment](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/011.htm) cleanly.

---

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct ConcreteExample {
  int* p;
  std::string s;

  ConcreteExample(int n, char const* s) : p(new int(n)), s(s) {}
  ConcreteExample(ConcreteExample const& other)
  : p(new int(*other.p)), s(other.s) {}
  ~ConcreteExample() { delete p; }

  ConcreteExample& operator=(ConcreteExample copy) {
    swap(*this, copy);
    return *this;
  }

  friend void swap(ConcreteExample& a, ConcreteExample& b) {
    using std::swap;
    //using boost::swap; // if available
    swap(a.p, b.p); // uses ADL (when p has a different type), the whole reason
    swap(a.s, b.s); // this 'method' is not really a member (so it can be used
                    // the same way)
  }
};

int main() {
  ConcreteExample a (3, "a"), b (5, "b");
  std::cout << a.s << *a.p << ' ' << b.s << *b.p << '\n';
  a = b;
  std::cout << a.s << *a.p << ' ' << b.s << *b.p << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Notice it works with either manually managed members (*p*) or RAII/SBRM-style members (*s*).

Comment: Not quite get it. Is the structure a template? So by swap, copy will be the original *this?

Comment: Thanks! Does the swap change "copy" too? Is this more than assignment?

Answer (score 14):

```
*this = rhs;
```

calls operator=(), which is the function you are writing. Cue infinite recursion, stack overflow, crash.

Also, if you used a std::vector rather than a C-style array, you probably would not need to implement operator=() at all.

Comment: Thanks, Neil! In my code, C array is prefered over std::vector. But it is still a possible solution.

Comment: If you prefer  C arrays over vectors, you are wrong, and making a huge amount of unecessary work for yourself.

Comment: The fact that you cant write the assignment operator correctly means that you probably don't know a whole host of other pitfalls associated with using dynamically allocated arrays. This means that you should definitely be using std::vector<>. Preferring a C array is not a reason but more a lack of understanding of what is really happening.

Comment: Neil: Unless you have allocation requirements that can't be expressed through the std::allocator interface required by std::vector.  Plus there are more resources which can be acquired and released than just memory, and pointers are often used as simply an example of that idiom (though I think you're right about this question).

Answer (score 4):

```
 *this = rhs;  // segment fault
```

This is definitively **not** the way to do it. You call `=` recursively, not calling the built in assignment operator. Assign variables one by one. Don't be lazy.

Comment: Thanks. I am lazy. So is it possible to call the default assignment operator?

Comment: No, once you declare your own, the compiler won't generate one (and couldn't, as it would have the same signature).

Answer (score 3):

The following line:

```
  *this = rhs;  // segment fault
```

will recursively call your `operator=()` function resulting in a stack overflow.

You should probably replace it with straight-forward assignments of the various member fields.

[As Neil said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996548/segmentation-fault-in-overloading-operator/1996561#1996561), using something like `std::vector<>` will remove much of the responsibility away from your code.  If for whatever reason you can't or don't want to use `std::vector<>`, you might also want to consider using the 'swap idiom' for your assignment operator.  This will make the function exception safe (if the allocation of the memory for `FeatureCount` array fails and throws an exception, the original object that's being assigned to will be left unchanged).  Something like the following:

```
void FeatureRandomCounts::swap( FeatureRandomCounts& other)
{
    FeatureCount* tmp_rects = other._rects;
    int tmp_dim             = other._dim;    // or whatever type _dim is

    // similarly for other members of FeatureRandomCounts...

    // now copy the other contents to 
    this->_rects = other._rects;
    this->_dim   = other._dim;

    // assign other members of rhs to lhs

    other._rects = tmp_rects;
    other._dim   = tmp_dim;

    // etc.

    return;
}
```

Now your assignment can look like:

```
FeatureRandomCounts &  FeatureRandomCounts::operator=(const FeatureRandomCounts &rhs)  
{  
    FeatureRandomCounts tmp( rhs);  // make a copy

    tmp.swap( *this);               // swap the contents of the copy and *this

    return *this;
                                    // the contents of tmp (which has the old 
                                    //  stuff that was in *this) gets destructed
}
```

Note that you need a proper copy constructor for this to work, but given the [Big 3 rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) you already need a proper copy ctor.

Comment: In your implementation of swap() you could at least use std::swap() to swap the actual members around.

Comment: @Martin - you're right, of course. I steered clear of `std::anything` because the OP indicated somewhere that he can't/won't use `std::vector`.  I should have made that clear and will update the answer later to indicate that `std::swap` should be used (actually, it should be an non-scoped `swap()` with a proper `using` declaration so the most appropriate `swap()` gets picked up, with `std::swap` being the last resort match).