# Is the class destructor called in an assignment?

Tags: c++

Does the class destructor get called when a variable that already holds an object receives another object in a c++ code?

```
Car car1;
Car car2;

car1 = car2;
```

Does the `car1` destructor get called in this situation?

Comment: Why not to try it in the code? Just print something to console from the destructor and see if it gets printed.

Comment: No, the destructor wont be called.

Comment: car1 and car2 are Car instances.

Comment: @RenanJosé then remove the parenthesis (), you're declaring functions instead of creating objects.

Comment: If the Car class has some vectors as class member how is the best way of freeing car 1 memory after the attribution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Destructor called on assignment between (stack) variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150543/destructor-called-on-assignment-between-stack-variables)

Comment: @RenanJosé, you can release car1 memory in the assignment operator, see the end of my answer.

Comment: [Possibly interesting read for you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: thanks guys. I will read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see in the following program that the destructor does not get called for t1 or t2 till the end of main() function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Test
{
    std::string _name;
public:
    Test(std::string name) : _name(name) { }
    ~Test()
    {
        std::cout << "Destructor " << _name << std::endl;
    }
    Test& operator=(const Test& fellow)
    {
        // avoid changing the name of the object
        std::cout << "Assignment operator " 
            << _name << "=" << fellow._name << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test t1("t1"), t2("t2");
    t1 = t2;
    return 0;
}
```

In an assignment `t1=t2`, just the assignment operator is called on `t1` taking `t2` as a parameter. If you need to release the resources of `t1`, you can do that in the assignment operator implemented as the code example shows. Don't forget to implement copy constructor too - that's for the cases of assignment to uninitialized instance (no need to release previously held resources because there are no resources held by the time of copy constructor call).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, move assignment operator would steal resources from t2, so that there would be nothing to release for destructor of t2. And move assignment operator is for cases like returning a temporary value from a function: t1 = f(). While copy assignment operator is for cases like the one discussed in this thread: t1=t2. What's wrong with releasing resources of t1 in copy assignment operator?

Comment: My mistake. I was misreading that as releasing the resources of the right hand side operand.

Comment: How release the resources of t1 in the assignment operator if the object is const?

Comment: @RenanJosé You cannot assign to `const` objects, so this question makes no sense.

Comment: A doubt. What is the assignment operator calling on t1 = t2;? t1 or t2?

Comment: @RenanJosé, for t1=t2 assignment operator having "t1" as "this" and "t2" as an argument is called. If t1 is const, you can still run t1=t2 if you declare an assignment operator as const and release resources which you declare as mutable. But this seems a bad style.

Answer (score 5):

The destructor of `car1` will *not* be executed when you do

```
car1 = car2;
```

Only the (probably implicitly generated) `Car::operator= (const Car&);` will be called on `car1`.

The destructor will only be called when `car1` goes out of scope (or when you call it explicitly, but you really rarely need that).

Also note that `car1` does not "hold" a `Car` instance, it *is* the instance itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
Car car1();//error， Car car1; call default construct function
Car car2(); //error, Car car2;call default construct function

car1 = car2; //call operator=()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends. If you allocate memory on the heap and assign one variable to another it wont call the destructor:

```
{
    Car* car1 = new Car();
    Car* car2 = new Car();
    car1 = car2;
}
```

But this will, and its because it goes out of scope not because of the copy assignment.

```
{
    Car car1;
    Car car2;
    car1 = car2;
}
```

Comment: What's so confusing. It pretty much shows you that the operator=() doesn't deallocate memory by default and the only reason the destructor gets called in example two is due to the scope and not the assignment itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
car1 = car2;
```

this causes the destructer of `car1`  NOT to be executed.
if you want the destructor  to be  called, `car1` needs to be called Explicitly or it should go out of scope.(as our Friend Baum mit Augen said, calling `car1` Explicitly is rarely in need).