# How to Use .lib file method in c program on GCC Compiler

Tags: c

I have following code:

.Lib file:

```
contain TRNG_GetRandomData( int *Data, int Size ); Method
```

.H file (header file):

```
extern void TRNG_GetRandomData( int *Data, int Size );
```

.C code (Source file):

```
#include<OpenDrivers.h>
void main()
{
    int  test[8] ; 
    TRNG_GetRandomData(test,8);
}
```

and i getting error

> undefined reference to `TRNG_GetRandomData`

Can any one help me solve it?

Comment: could you edit with your gcc compile command. Also you compile with gcc under windows (MinGW  ?) ?

Comment: I am using GCC fileName.c command at a time and using windows 7 (32 bit)

Comment: you need to tell compiler to link with the library something like gcc fileName.c -L<path_to_lib> -l<name_of_the_lib>

Comment: Exactly , i am not getting how to link .lib file to header file or source code . could you please suggest how i Will do it ?

Comment: After Using  "gcc MyProg.c myLib.lib" Command i found following error

C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-min
gw32/bin/ld.exe: unknown architecture of input file myLib.lib(trng.o)' is
 incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6VqOqa.o:MyProg.c:(.text+0x1a): undefined re
ference to `TRNG_GetRandomData'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: "unknown architecture of input file myLib.lib(trng.o)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64" - is this a Windows build of the library? Can you rebuild it yourself? Or it might be a 32-bit library whereas you're building as 64-bit: can you try compiling with -m32 ?

Comment: Thank you Rup for your reply , now my first question will be is it possible to call a method from .lib file because when i looking it on internet there are a lot of examples there but with the .O file or .SO file , i did not get any example with .lib file ..

Answer (score 2):

You need to add option -l infront of your lib file (without the .lib extension) in your Makefile.
I am guessing there is some linking issues with header files, are you sure the header files are properly included?

Btw, you can also refer to this question : [What are Header Files and Library Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6407975/8499897)
Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I can't add comment under your question and hence i posted this as an answer

Comment: Also, the [order matters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45135/2472827).

Answer (score 0):

I solved similar problem by extracting all object files from *.lib file and adding these files to linker.

```
ar x lib3rd_party.lib
gcc <flags> -o my_target my_obj1.o my_obj2.o ... 3rd_party_obj1.o 3rd_party_obj2.o ...
```

It worked. Then I made some "improvement". I "repacked" these object files to static *.a library.

```
ar r libmylib.a 3rd_party_obj1.o 3rd_party_obj2.o ...
```

And linked my project with it:

```
gcc <flags> -static -L<libmylib.a_location> -o my_target my_obj1.o my_obj2.o ... -lmylib
```

It worked too. Note `-lmylib` must go after object files.